# How to make a number round to eight decimal places and with the different color?

Tags: javascript, string, numbers, decimal

Apologies for asking what looks like a comment asked question but I cannot seem to be able to solve.

How do I write 0.2 to round to eight decimal places and make it with the different color, such as belows

[image]

Could anyone tell me how to solve ??

Thank you very much!

Comment: You can use `toFixed(8)` to round to 8 dp

Comment: `Math.round(1.2345678906 * 100000000) / 100000000`.

Comment: @AjAX. What about the trailing zeros?

Comment: What do you mean by make it with different color? Like displaying it on page?

Comment: Which steps have you taken to solve this?

Comment: @user184994 https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11832914/round-to-at-most-2-decimal-places-only-if-necessary#comment42416958_11832950

Comment: thank you! but how to make it with different color like in the example?@user184994

Comment: @Sylvia maybe the answer help you in this

Comment: I would like to change the color finally @Jonas W.

Comment: @Sylvia did you see the answer?

Comment: yes, like displaying it on page @Matus Dubrava

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to follow these steps:

1. Create a fixed string representation of the number using `toFixed(8)` which gives you 8 decimal places.
2. Get the substring to separate it into two parts as you desired to apply different color to each part.
3. Create a `span` element for that each parts and add a class to them.
4. Add this final HTML in your web page.

```js
function changeNum(elemId, num){
  var fixed8 = num.toFixed(8);
  var substrWhite = fixed8.substr(0, fixed8.indexOf('.')+3);
  var substrGrey = fixed8.substr(fixed8.indexOf('.')+3, fixed8.length);
  var nHTML = "<span class='white'>"+substrWhite+"</span><span class='grey'>"+substrGrey+"</span>"
  document.getElementById(elemId).innerHTML = nHTML;
}

var num = 0.2;
changeNum('content1', num);
num = 0.56;
changeNum('content2', num);
num = 0.123;
changeNum('content3', num);
```

```css
.white{
  color: white;
}
.grey{
  color: grey;
}
div{
  background: #444;
}
```

```html
<div id='content1'></div>
<div id='content2'></div>
<div id='content3'></div>
```

Comment: Thanks for your help!

Comment: @Sylvia happy to help

Comment: [`toFixed()` is — not — browser consistent.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11832914/round-to-at-most-2-decimal-places-only-if-necessary)

Comment: @AjAX. there are still many such methods that are not browser consistent like say `includes()` which do not work in IE. Does that mean we cannot or should not use it. It depends on your preference for that.